# MySQL equivalent of LIKE '*'

Tags: mysql, ms-access

In the MS Access I was able to use LIKE '*' after a where clause to return all rows from a column. This doesn't appear to work in MySQL.

What MySQL statement is closest to this in functionality?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why would you want to "match any" when that's the default.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean why would you ever want to match *everything* when that's the default? Are you loking for rows where that column isn't `NULL`?

Comment: Is there a version of the answer which will provide nulls as well as not nulls?

Comment: If you don't write any `where`, you will get all rows. So `select * from tablename` will give you all rows from that table. Is that what you are looking for? If you WANT a where clause, maybe `... where 1=1`?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL equivalent:

```
LIKE '%'
```

..................

Comment: That's a condition that makes no sense. It's like `WHERE 1=1`.

Comment: That isn't the point, the OP just wanted to know the equivalent mechanism. Obviously it can be combined with the real search parameters to form the desired where clause, once this is known.